# css footer contains center doc

Tags: css

I appear to have a peculiar problem.

I've got the following code snippet and as you can see i've just added the footer div at the end:

```
<body>
    <div id="conainer">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <p>this is the wrapper</p>
            <div id="centerDoc">
                <p>this is the centerDoc</p>
            </div>  <!--centerDoc !-->
        </div> <!-- wrapper !-->
    </div> <!--container !-->
    <div id="footer">
        <p>footer</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

I get the follwing output [I added borders to see whats going on]:

[image: The output:]

I hope you can see that the centerDoc div is inside the footer div and i don't understand why.

CSS for divs:

```css
#container {
   margin:auto;
   width: 100%;
}

#wrapper{
    width:80%;
    border:1px dashed black;
}

#centerDoc {
   margin-top:2.8%;
   margin-left:10px;

   float:left;
   width: 100%;
   border:1px dashed black;
}

#footer{
    text-align:center;
    color:#333333;
    border:1px dashed black;
}
```

Any pointers to sort this out is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@animuson is right. you may use "clear: both;" to fix it. see below

```
<pre>
#footer{
    text-align: center;
    color: #333333;
    border: 1px dashed black;
    clear: both;
}
</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks. that appears to have it sit under the centerDoc. Just one additional question, adding a margin-top doesn't seem to add any space to it. The only way to accomplish this is when i add the border. Any idea why? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That is normal behavior. Your `#centerDoc` division is **floated left**, so it's position is correct. However, because it's floated, it's removed from the flow of the document, so it's not included in the height of the wrapper division and the footer division fills in behind it, then the text moves down so that it's not behind other content.